# Why does .sort() actually change the variable?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I came across the sort method and I want to understand why running sort.() actually changes the list and I don't have to reassign it?

```
>>> list = [88,1,4,56,9,7,8,9]
>>> list
[88, 1, 4, 56, 9, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 56, 88]
```

Comment: Because `sorted(..)` does not.

Comment: Because it is designed like that? Try `sorted` instead (and btw, don't name your variables as something that already exists).

Comment: Because it does? There isn't a hard and fast rule on what modifies the actual variable, and what returns as modified copy. The only rule is that only one of the above happens. (There are exceptions like 'pop()')

Comment: Python always provides different ways to do same thing. :)  You have two choices: sorted(yourlist) vs. yourlist.sort(). sorted(yourlist) will not change yourlist and you have to reassign it if you want to change yourlist. yourlist.sort() will do it in one step.

Comment: Do you want to know *why* they made it work that way, or *how* it's possible for it to work that way?

Comment: @user2357112 both. In particular, why something like my_string.upper() does not reassign it but .sort() on a list does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, because it can.
Lists are mutable objects, so the `sort()` method *can* modify it. There's  already a `sorted()` function, so it doesn't make much sense to have it leave the object unmodified.
Strings are immutable, so they cannot be modified in place. The `upper()` method cannot modify the original string.

Comment: Historically speaking, there wasn't already a `sorted` function; that came later. (See the 1.4 docs, where [`list.sort` was a thing](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node12.html) and [`sorted` wasn't](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node26.html). Also see the "New in version 2.4." note on the docs for `sorted` in the 2.x line.) The mutable/immutable distinction is important, though.

Comment: I didn't know that; I was a bit too late the party. I think the broader point remains though. It's an option for lists, which are mutable, but not for strings.

Answer (score 1):

.sort() is a method of the list class. which means when it is called is directly changes the list stored inside of the class.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. The fact that it's a instance method doesn't mean that it necessarily has to alter the instance. It would be entirely possible to have `sorted` be an instance member and still return a sorted copy.

Comment: Indeed, `.copy()`, `.index()` and `.count()` for instance do not.

Comment: This is *part* of a an adequate answer. Because `sort` is a method it has access to the instance information. `sort` has been deliberately designed to do what it does, and *can* do it. The ability to do it is essential.